# Android Studio 2.3 Unknown Error

Tags: android, android-studio

Has anyone faced this issue after updating to the recently launched Android Studio 2.3? Seems that this error does not affect anything and it only shows on messages. There is no stack trace with regards to it or anything. Building the APK or debugging with these errors do not affect the code in any way.

Project is using Gradle 2.3.0.

[image: Error Messages]

Here is my grade-wrapper.properties.

[image]

Comment: No it will not effect in any way but may I know the version of gradle you are using?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Using gradle 2.3.0!

Comment: You need to run `app:lint`, probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, screenLayout within each Activity's config is the culprit. I shouldn't have done that. Doing it would result in an error without any stack trace or whatsoever.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older version of Gradle, then update it by simple steps:

Go to Gradle scripts and then open the `gradle-wrapper.properties` and replace the `distributionUrl` with this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

Then start the Gradle sync again with a working internet connection.

Comment: Same issue tho!

Comment: @Nicholas your problem still alive?